# Can I pack a razor in a carry-on on planes leaving Toronto Pearson airport?

Tags: canada, airport-security, hand-luggage, eu

Can I?  Never carried a razor before.  The women's Gillete safety razor?  Now, I'm pretty sure the TSA are good with it but I read on the Transport Canada  site which was updated on 2011 that razors aren't allowed?

By the way, are Europeans okay with razors in general?

Edit:  Safety razor!

Comment: Do you mean [old-school safety razors with disposable double-edged blades](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/Chrome-Safety-Razor.jpg) or [modern-day disposable razors](http://krikor.info/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/venus-line.png) which are sometimes called safety razors ([wikipedia for example includes them in its dedicated article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safety_razor#Recent_changes)).

Comment: I did once carry a one-use-only razor for shaving. They made me trash it :)

Answer (score 6):

#### Canada

The [Canadian TSA website](http://www.catsa.gc.ca/complete-item-list?keys=Disposable%20%28safety%29%20razors%20and%20blade%20cartridges&submit.x=20&submit.y=24&field_wtp_category_tid=All&nid=) says that you can indeed pack disposable razors and cartridges in your carry-on:

> #### Disposable (safety) razors and blade cartridges
>
> - Carry On Baggage: Yes
> - Checked Baggage: Yes

#### European Union

Whereas [the website of the European TSA-equivalent organisation](http://ec.europa.eu/transport/modes/air/security/info_travellers_en.htm) mentions razors (without mentioning disposable or not) and the fact that they are prohibited in carry-on luggage:

> ### LIST OF PROHIBITED ARTICLES IN YOUR CABIN BAGGAGE:
>
> [...]
>
> #### c. objects with a sharp point or sharp edge (objects with a sharp point or sharp edge capable of being used to cause serious injury), including:
>
> - [...]
> - razor blades,

For future reference, [here is the list of prohibited items on flights originatin within the EU.](http://ec.europa.eu/transport/modes/air/security/doc/info_travellers_restricted_art.pdf)

#### UK

As [@chx correctly points out](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43300/can-i-pack-a-razor-in-a-carry-on-on-planes-leaving-toronto-pearson-airport/43302?noredirect=1#comment80821_43302), UK is also in Europe. According to the [governmental authorities](https://www.gov.uk/hand-luggage-restrictions/personal-items), disposable razors are allowed in both carry-ons and hold luggage:

[image: uk razors]

Comment: +1 Thanks for the future reference. I'm really saddened that I can't take a catapult with me though..

Comment: @JoErNanO since your link does not distinct between disposable blades and straight razors. See https://www.gov.uk/hand-luggage-restrictions/personal-items for UK which is the strictest, http://www.frankfurt-airport.com/content/frankfurt_airport/en/misc/container/airport-guide/english/jcr:content.file/2014-01-06-airportguide_en-fro.pdf for Germany and if you want I can dig more but disposable is good anywhere.

Comment: @chx Yes I often forget that UK is in Europe. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Flimzy That's what I thought too. However I was unable to discern if that was the case from the way the question in phrased. Therefore, I went by the assumption that the [gillette woman safety razor](http://krikor.info/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/venus-line.png) is the disposable one.

Comment: The UK is part of the EU so it's also within the same framework, no reason to single it out. But the EU commission Directorate General for Mobility and Transport is nothing like the TSA, it enacts rules that are implemented by national authorities (hence the potential discrepancies or possibly additional rules) and has many other roles but does not train or hire screeners or operate security checkpoints.

Comment: I would think "razor blade" refers to [this](http://reprap.org/mediawiki/images/8/85/Razor_blade_rec.jpg) rather than [that](http://globe-views.com/dcim/dreams/razor/razor-05.jpg).

Comment: Once again: your answer is incorrect / misleading . The link you provided does not discern between the two kind of razors. I've already given you UK and Germany. Please remove yours.